# С# + MySQL вывод информации взятой из другой таблицы

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть код

```
            string connStr = "Database=DB1;Data Source=localhost;User Id=user;Password=password;SslMode=none";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM `j_1`.`j_members` WHERE `group` LIKE '15'";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
```

Как мне переписать код так, чтобы я мог получить значения из другой таблицы подставив туда значение из таблицы j_members

```
string sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `j_1`.`j_purchases` WHERE `id` LIKE 'reader[0]'";
```

Грубо говоря, мне надо найти в таблице j_members id всех пользователей с группой 15, найти в таблице j_purchases соответствующие id из таблицы j_members  и вывести в listBox1 время покупки "j_StartTime" и время окончания "j_EndTime" Подскажите как в C# написать данный код

Comment: По сути вам в первом случае надо получить набор id (лист или массив), потом перебором получить набор времен из j_purchases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, тут нужно править не C# код, а SQL. Сделайте запрос таким образом:

```
"select j_purchases.id, j_members.j_StartTime, j_members.j_EndTime
from j_members join j_purchases on j_purchases.id = j_members.id where
WHERE j_purchases.group LIKE '15'"
```

И добавляйте в listBox reader[0] (id), reader[1] (startTime), reader[2] (endTime).

Comment: Да, только запрос не правильный, в таблице j_members нету j_StartTime и j_EndTime, они находятся в j_purchases и в j_purchases нету group, group находиться в j_members

Comment: Запрос поправил, работает, спасибо

Comment: Запутался в j_<что-то там>, но суть постарался передать:) Рад, что помог!